# Configuring Babel and Jest

Tags: node.js, babeljs, jestjs, babel-jest

**TLDR:** How can I configure `jest` so that it uses `babel` to compile the test files *and* the files required in `globalSetup` and `globalTeardown`?

---

I've been struggling a lot to configure `jest` and `babel`. It seems that when I run my tests `babel` fails to load the configuration file, or perhaps it doesn't run at all.

*in* ***package.json:***

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node src/index.js",
    "test": "jest src/tests/*.test.js",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "@babel/node": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "jest": "^23.5.0",
  }
}
```

*in* ***babel.config.js:***

```
module.exports = (api) => {
    if (api) api.cache(true);
    const presets = ['@babel/preset-env'];
    const plugins = [];
    return {
        presets,
        plugins,
    };
};
```

*in* ***jest.config.js:***

```
module.exports = {
    globalSetup: './src/config/jest/setup',
    globalTeardown: './src/config/jest/teardown',
};
```

---

When I run `npm run test` I get the following error:

```
import app from '../../index';
^^^^^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

...which I assume means that `babel` failed to configure properly. I tried logging on both config files and `babel.config.js` is only run when I do `npm start`.

When I used an identical configuration with `.babelrc` instead, the tests could run. However the `globalSetup` and `globalTeardown` could not.

Comment: So when I run `npm start` I use `babel-node` and it does some magic compilation it seems. I would like to use `babel-node` when I do my jest testing too I guess?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use babel-preset-env with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45259679/how-to-use-babel-preset-env-with-jest)

Answer (score 8):

Jest currently doesn't transform modules defined in `globalSetup` and `globalTeardown`. There's an open GitHub discussion [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5164).

That being said, there are some workarounds on the same thread. You'll have to require `babel-register` and `babel-polyfill` on top of your `jest.config.js`. Here is the full implementation: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5164#issuecomment-366139663

If someone is using TypeScript requiring `ts-node/register` should make it work. https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5164#issuecomment-376006851